# Facebook app, how to have a online version with a local version?

Tags: facebook

Hi so i recently uploaded my facebook app. so i can only input 1 url for Website with Facebook Login. So how do i keep working on my local version while still serving the online version??

Answer (score 0):

get another API and app secret from

`www.facebook.com/developers`

Comment: is that the only solution? means i have to keep two seperate keys one for online one for local?